# Error occurs in the template of component upperCaseComponent

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-template

It shows an error with the template,

Errors:

- Property 'result' is private and only accessible within class 'upperCaseComponent'
- Property 'mymessage' is not declared in 'upperCaseComponent'

my html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mymessage"
<button (click)="clickMe()"> send</button>
<br><br>
<h1>{{result | json}}</h1>
```

my component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
export class MyComponent {
private result: any;
constructor()
}
```

Comment: Have you defined "mymessage" inside uppercase.component.ts?

Comment: you are accessing `private` ts variable `result` in template. make `result` variable as `public` in your component file

Comment: Please add dependent code file when you are adding some error question. Like here you can share the template and component.ts file as both are dependent on each other.

Comment: i have attached another image you can see the code

Comment: have you defined myMessage variable in your ts? Make result property public

Comment: You need to provide more code for us to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here the error say it not able to find variable 'mymessage' in uppercase.component.ts

```
export class UpperCaseComponent {
 public results: any; // Change it private to public
 public mymessage: any;
}
```

If you are trying to access variable within template you need to declare it as public as if you declare it as private it would be accessible only within class

Answer (score 3):

welcome to SO.

Regarding your question, could you please give me a confirmation on the below points so that I can help you in a better way.

1. Can you please edit the question and post the component code here. (You can mask the sensitive data here).
2. Please check if you are using binding data is marked `private`?

Answer (score 2):

`UpperCaseComponent.ts` has result field as `private`, `uppercase.component.html` cannot access it so make result field as public. 
As for `myMessage` field as it's not defined anywhere in the `UpperCaseComponent.ts` I assume you want to set it from the parent component, then create an `@Input` `myMessage` field in `UpperCaseComponent.ts` and use it in the template. Bind this from parent component wherever you want to use this UpperCaseComponent

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this**:

```
export class upperCaseComponent {
  result: any;
  mymessage: String;

  ...  // other code goes here
}
```

Comment: I made the result as public and declared a variable as public in component, it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

```
input type="checkbox" name="application{{ application.id }}" id="application-{{ application.id }}"
class="form-check-input" value="richiesta_{{ application.id }}" [(ngModel)]="model[application + i]">
```

i have on my HTML when I put `model['application' + i]">`

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.  Please consider improving your answer.